# Save data to SPO using third party app

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, third-party-software

I have different users that are **unlicensed**.

I want to ask if i can create a **portal**, or use a **third party app** to let the user fill a specific form.

When they **submit** this form i want to save the form data of the users on SharePoint list. **(Witout giving them any kind of License)**

Is it possible to achieve this ? if yes, there is any tutorial that i can follow up ?

Any help would be appriciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An external user is someone outside of your organization who can access your SharePoint Online sites and documents but does not have a license for your SharePoint Online or Microsoft Office 365 subscription. External users are not employees or onsite agents for you or your affiliates.

You do not need to buy licenses for adding external users to SharePoint Online. Also, you can add unlimited external users.

You can create a form directly in the list and then allow them to modify the item when you share it with them.

More information:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/external-sharing-overview

https://sharegate.com/blog/ultimate-guide-deal-with-office-365-external-sharing